# Translating the 'types' Field in Google Places API Response to Italian

Tags: python, google-places-api

I'm working with the Google Places API and trying to get the response in Italian, specifically for the 'types' field. I have set the 'language' parameter to 'it' in my request, and I've also added the 'Accept-Language' header with the value 'it'. However, the 'types' field still returns values in English.

Here's the code snippet for my request:

```
import requests

endpoint_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json"
params = {
    'key': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    'input': 'company_name',
    'inputtype': 'textquery',
    'fields': 'place_id,name,formatted_address,geometry,types',
    'location': 'location',
    'language': 'it'
}
headers = {'Accept-Language': 'it'}

response = requests.get(endpoint_url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

thanx if you can provide me a solution.

Is there a way to translate the 'types' field into Italian, or are these values standard identifiers that are the same across all languages? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm assuming that you're using python here right? I edited your question also to improve formatting. Now with regards to your question, do you mean that you only want to change the language of the  `types` field itself? instead of the value it returns?

Answer (score 0):

### The `language` parameter is used to set the language in which to return results

The `language` parameter is not used to change the language of the `fields`, but is used to translate the **address components** (As best as it can). See documentation for more info:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#language

Also, you are correct in this statement,

> *"are these values standard identifiers that are the same across all languages?"*

Google Maps API have a [table](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types?hl=it) for such **Place Types** and if you go to the top right corner of the page and use the drop down button to change language into Italian, you can see that the whole page is translated to such **except** for the types properties, in which that stayed in english.

If you want, you can file a feature request to the Public Issue Tracker and include your use case that you think might help the Google Engineers consider such feature to be added to the APIs: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker

With that said, I hope these information helps!

Comment: Thank you, I inserted a feature request. https://issuetracker.google.com/297608733
best

Comment: Great! If this answer was able to help, feel free to upvote / accept to indicate that my answer was helpful to the community.